# Getting Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now - when restoring batch of MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench, database-restore

I'm using version MySQL Workbench 6.07 and MySQL Community Server 5.6.11-log

Basically my database has over 200 triggers.

I've taken a backup of the triggers, and am trying to apply these to another database that has the same table structures.

The problem I'm getting is when I copy the DROP TRIGGER and CREATE TRIGGER statements (for all triggers) and paste the statements in MySQL Workbench, when I then execute all of them together, after about the 5th trigger I get the error...

> Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command
>   now.

Could the problem be to do with the number of statements being executed ?  Is there a setting I need to change on the MySQL server, because if I just run the statement for the query in which the problem occurs it executes fine.

For your information the max_allowed_packet size in MySQL is already set to 512mb

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Do I need to provide any further information to get a response.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what you actually execute? Post the first 20 or so lines (or as many as to show the all triggers up to the one that causes the error). I assume you have set the delimiter to a non-standard one.